# Removing a file and symbolic linking in a single step

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

Currently I have this code:

```
rm -f /etc/file.conf
ln -s /etc/configuration/file.conf /etc/file.conf
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in a single step, without having to first delete the original. I have tried to look up the various flags for symbolic linking without much luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell `ln` to drop the destination file with the `-f` option

```
ln -fs /etc/configuration/file.conf /etc/file.conf
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was after